# Does an app's receipt creation date get reset after an app delete?

Tags: ios, app-store, storekit, receipt, receipt-validation

Let's say an app was installed from the App Store on October 20 2017.
The user deleted the app a month ago and reinstalled the app today.

Would the receipt's Creation Date be October 20, 2017, or today's date?

And a follow-up question is, does this behavior change if the app is running in the sandbox environment?

I could not find any of this information in the Apple documentation, nor in any other posts in any developer forums. I tried investigating this by checking the receipt creation date when running a debug build, but kept getting the current date.

Also [posted this question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/302379#302379) on the Apple Developer forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the app's receipt creation date gets reset after an app delete (this is for apps without auto-renewal subscriptions)

I tested this by NSLogging the receipt creation date and testing with an app downloaded from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

With an auto-renewal subscription, the receipt shows the original purchase date regardless of an App delete, reinstall or launching on a new device (e.g. restore purchases).